# How to compile a file to view in .pdf file in Gummi

Tags: pdftex, ubuntu, gummi

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and I'm new with LaTeX and I don't find that how to compile a `Test.tex` file to view in `.pdf` format.

How I reach it, need help?

Comment: Do you need to use Gummi?

Comment: File --> Export to PDF?

Comment: @JuriRobl , actually my friend suggest me and I saw It's rating is high that's why I prefer this, otherwise not. If you know better than Gummi than please???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gummi will continuously update the preview that you see in the editor, so what you see in the Preview pane is a PDF. It is however created in a temporary directory it seems, so to save a PDF to a folder of your choice, select File --> Export to PDF (keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>).